# How to display and compute time in java

Tags: java, timer, clock

I am building a java application.I need to monitor how long the user is staying on a particular page.The timer should start on user entering the page.It should pause on user moving away to another page and resumes when user returns to the "page(panel)".It should work like a stopwatch on a particular panel.

Comment: By "page" do you mean web page?  If so this is completely impossible.

Comment: Not webpage.But a jpanel that opens on buttonclick. I have to know how long the panel is being viewed.

Comment: Still impossible. How do you know the user didn't stop to answer the phone or get a cup of coffee, or go out to lunch, or ....

Comment: Even then i can detect how long the page(panel) is there.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of Stopwatch implementations floating around.  I know the Guava library as one:  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html.  We use one called Java Simon to measure the time it takes to make it through a REST call:  https://code.google.com/p/javasimon/

I don't think there is anything for free that will record the timing of page transitions through a JPanel, so you're going to need to figure out the event model yourself.  But the stopwatch logic itself is really simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without detecting that the user actually sits in front of the screen, you can simply use System.currentTimeMillis intialized when user enters the page.

Another option is to use the [JAMon API](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/), it comes with AOP.